# Regular audio glitches on Linux with Scarlett 3rd gen USB interface

Tags: linux, usb, audio, linux-kernel, real-time

I have a Scarlett 18i20 audio interface running well on a Samsung laptop with Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia and with the 5.0.21-rt16 real time kernel with fully preemptive configuration.

The same set up on a desktop machine results in regular audio glitches between 3 and 4 seconds apart. I am testing with a sine wave in puredata and the problem occurs with alsa and with jack. The problem occurs with other audio apps too.

I came across a similar problem on this link:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/982882/audio-glitches-every-few-seconds-with-vlc-and-the-alc1220-codec/985596

The solution was related to the "system RTC clock having about a 4% drift" and was solved using the adjtimexconfig utility. When I run this utility, after stopping the NTP server, it reports:

```
 Adjusting system time by -11.4326 sec/day to agree with CMOS clock...done.
```

"adjtimex -p" reveals the following:

```
         mode: 0
   offset: 14679795
frequency: 4435324
 maxerror: 289636
 esterror: 22136
   status: 8193 
time_constant: 7
precision: 1
tolerance: 32768000
     tick: 9998
 raw time:  1582195310s 628559316us = 1582195310.628559316
```

The adjustment however makes no improvement in the glitches.

For the hardware set up of the desktop, please see:

https://escuta.org/tmp/hardware.txt